# ошибка при запуске spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails

доброго дня.

#### `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.1'
# ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'ruby_dep'
gem 'rubocop'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-bundler', require: false
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'childprocess'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'libnotify'
end

gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

при запуске spork получаю очень длинный список ошибок, начинающийся с

```
slim@slim-VirtualBox ~/projects/ruby/exp2 $ spork
Using RSpec, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
/home/slim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
Loading Spork.prefork block...
/home/slim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/slim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
/home/slim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:125:in `is_a?'
```

в чем проблема?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

проблема оказалась в совместимости гемов, как и было указано ответом выше)
в общем, есть человек, убивший кучу, видимо, времени, но нашедший решение) за что ему лучи добра))) я убил на поиски решения 4 дня. ниже Gemfile, который содержит правильные совместимости

source 'https://rubygems.org'
  ruby '2.3.1'

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
  gem 'guard-bundler', require: false
  gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
  gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
  gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :development, :test do

```
gem 'sqlite3'   
gem 'capybara', '2.2.0'
gem 'rspec-rails', '3.3.2'
gem 'guard-rspec', '4.6.0'
gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'guard-spork', '2.1.0'
gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
```

end

```
group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0' 

end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

взято [отсюда](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/issues/55) и немного изменено под свои нужды.. но суть та же. надеюсь, кому-то поможет

Comment: благодарю, исправил

Comment: извините мне мою нескромность, что я свое решение отметил, как лучшее, но именно оно и помогло...

Answer (score 0):

## Установите ту же версию Ruby, что используется в учебнике

В Ruby 2.4 классы `Fixnum` и `Bignum` признаны устаревшими, а их функциональность сведена в один класс `Integer`. Многие старые библиотеки не готовы к такому повороту событий и требуют либо обновления, либо удаления.

Скорее всего, на 2.3 и ниже всё заведётся, но лучше использовать именно ту версию, что указана в вашем учебном материале.

Comment: Делал все один в один по учебнику сначала, но ошибки все таки появлялись. Немного погуглив, решал. Но вот эту никак... Была версия 2.0.0, не помогло... Наверное, можно и без spork обойтись, но интересен сам факт - почему ошибка...

Comment: @НиколайЕфимов на 2.0.0 ошибка должна быть другой.

Comment: такая же была... один в один... хз